Visual Studio documents are not opening
After updating my Visual Studio recently, I ran into a problem. Now when I [Ctrl + Left-click] on a method, a page named 'sourcelink' opens as if the code is already compiled.

But before, a page would open with explanations (exceptions - output and input - descriptions for each input on why it's there...) written as "comments" in each method , and I want that...

How can I fix that?! Visual Studio: version 2022-17.10.0 C#
